# Ruby on Rails "SystemStackError Stack level too deep" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm pretty new to Ruby on Rails and i'm trying to build a simple blogging platform that allows user authentication using devise. When I fill out the posts form which takes a title and content field, when I press the "create post" button i get an error that reads

```
SystemStackError in PostsController#create stack level too deep
```

It seems as if the "create" action in my PostsController is where the problem stems from. Can any one help me? This is how my PostsController looks:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

    before_action :authenticate_user! 

    def index
      @posts = Post.all 
    end 

    def new 
      @post = Post.new
    end 

    def create
      @post = Post.new(params[:post])
    end 

    def show 
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end 

    private 

    def params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content)
    end


end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easy, you call `params` method in the body of `params` method (recursively) - boom, infinite loop. Change the name of your custom `params` method:

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params)
  # etc.
end

# ...

def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content)
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot bro!! worked!!